# Nest not recognizing POST from fetch request

Tags: javascript, http, nestjs

I have a react application running on port 3000 making a POST request to my NestJS server on port 8080. My client is:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/confirm-reservation', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
     },
     mode: 'cors',
     data: {
         key: 'this is a value'
      }
})
```

And the controller is a simple

```
@Controller('confirm-reservation')
export class AppController {
    @Post()
    postForm(@Body() form:any) {
        console.log(form)
     }
}
```

on my main server i have `app.enableCors();`

When i submit the request i get an empty `{}`

I am able to make the request using Postman with the same headers as my browser and able to see the req object in the server but not from using the fetch. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `body` property in the options object, there is no `data` property. Then send the data as JSON.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/confirm-reservation', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  },
  mode: 'cors',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    key: 'this is a value'
  })
})
```

Comment: oh my, what a miss there. Thank you!